# Nothing but "packed" records -- should I fix it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, record, packed

While reviewing some code in our legacy Delphi 7 program, I noticed that everywhere there is a record it is marked with `packed`. This of course means that the record is stored byte-for-byte and not aligned to be faster for the CPU to access. The packing seems to have been done blindly as an attempt to outsmart the compiler or something -- basically valuing a few bytes of memory instead of faster access

An example record:

```
TFooTypeRec = packed record
    RID                 : Integer;
    Description         : String;
    CalcInTotalIncome   : Boolean;
    RequireAddress      : Boolean;
end;
```

Should I fix this and make every record normal or "not" packed? Or with modern CPUs and memory is this negligible and probably a waste of time? Are there any problems that can result from unpacking?

Comment: Also in the example you gave, unpacking wouldn't result in faster access: the first two fields are already aligned, Boolean are bytes and don't need alignment. And in the greater scheme of things larger aligned structures can be less efficient if the data accessed no longer fits in CPU cache (L1 is still just a few dozens kilobytes on modern CPUs). So you risk breaking code that works just to end up with potentially lower performance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to answer this question without a full understanding of how each of those packed records are used in your application code.  It is the same as asking "Should I change this variable declaration from Int64 to Byte ?"

Without knowing what values that variable will be expected and required to maintain the answer could be yes.  Or it could be no.

Similarly in your case.  If a record *needs* to be packed then it should be *left* packed.  If it does not need to be packed then there is no harm in not packing it.  If you are not sure or cannot tell, then the safest course is to leave them as they are.

As a guide to making this determination (should you decide to proceed), situations where record packing is required or recommended include:

- persistence of record values
- sharing of record values with [potentially] differently compiled code
- strict compatibility with externally defined structures
- deliberately overlaying a type layout over differently structured memory

This isn't necessarily an exhaustive list, and what these all have in common is:

- records comprising a series of values in adjacent bytes that must and can be relied upon by any potential producer or consumer of the record without possibility of interference from the compiler or other factors

What I would recommend is that (if possible and practical) you determine what purpose packing serves in each case and add documentation to that effect to the record declaration itself so that anyone in the future with the same question doesn't have to go through that discovery process, e.g.:

```
  type
    TSomeRecordType = packed record
      // This record must be packed as it is used for persistence
      ..
    end;

    TSomeExternType = packed record
      // This record must be packed as it is required to be compatible
      //  in memory with an externally defined struct (ref: extern code docs)
      ..
    end;
```

Answer (score 8):

The main idea of using packed records is *not* that you save a few bytes of memory! Instead, it is about guaranteeing that the variables are where you expect them to be in memory. Without such a guarantee, it would be impossible (or, at least, difficult) to manage memory manually on the heap and write to and read from files.

Hence, the program might malfunction if you 'unpack' the records!

Comment: +1. Do not mess around unnecessarily with legacy code unless you have a complete regression test available.

Answer (score 2):

If the record is stored/retrieved as packed or transfered in any way to a receiver that expects it to be packed, then do not change it.

Update :

There is a string type declared in your example. It looks suspicious, since storing the record  in a binary file will not preserve the string content.

Comment: Mainly these records are used to store some information and pass it around within the program among different classes and what not. There could be a portion of code that relies on the actual order of each byte, but I know that not every record needs to be packed

Comment: Anyway, better not touch the packed declaration. No gain, only risk of overlooking some important reason why it was declared like this.

Comment: And for lack of "important reason", there may be a "side effect" that can't be easily accounted for.

Comment: @LU RD - re `string`: I guess the code is compiled with `{$LONGSTRINGS OFF}` so that `Description` in reality is a `ShortString`.

Answer (score 0):

- Packed record have length exactly size like members are.
- No packed record are optimised (thay are aligned -> consequently higher) for better performance.